# How to call external api to pull data into json format?

Tags: 7, javascript

There is an api that is used to expose data from an external website. How can I use the drupal API to call the external api and pull the data into json format?

the external api would be, for example, "api.website.com/api/get_data".

return results would be in json format "{"data":[....]}

How would I use a module to call the external api and return the data in json?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you wish to do with said data.

If you are looking for a purely code approach, you could do something like:

```
$response = drupal_http_request($url);
$result = json_decode($response->data);
```

If you want a Rules based approach, you could could use the [Rules HTTP Client](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_http_client) module, which allows you to do essentially the same as the above code but via the Rules UI.

Comment: awesome, this worked perfectly. thank you for quick response.

Comment: I also have a module in development on GitHub with allows you to define APIs, including their responses, allowing you to expose an API directly to modules like Views, Rules and Migrate. It's been a while since I've worked on it, but I recall it being relatively stable: https://github.com/Realityloop/apihub

Answer (score 2):

Drupal offers two functions for encoding and decoding JSON. To encode an array into `JSON usedrupal_json_encode()` and to decode a JSON object into an array use the - can you guess it? -`drupal_json_decode()` function.

**Encoding JSON**

First, let’s look at encoding an array into JSON. Take this array for example:

```
$array = array('Boat', 'Car', 'Ship', 'Building');
```

If we were to encode the above array into JSON, you will get `["Boat","Car","Ship","Building"]` returned. Here is a code example:

```
$array = array('Boat', 'Car', 'Ship', 'Building');
$output = drupal_json_encode($array);
// $output will be ["Boat","Car","Ship","Building"]
```

**Decoding JSON**

Now let's look at decoding a JSON object. If you were to running the following code:

```
$json = '["Boat","Car","Ship","Building"]';  
return drupal_json_decode($json);
```

The `drupal_json_decode()` function will return an array.

**Pulling In JSON Objects**

The next example I want to demonstrate is how to pull in a Twitter account using Twitter's GET users/show REST API.

First, we’ll need to get the JSON object and for this we’ll use the drupal_http_request() function:

```
$request = drupal_http_request('https://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json?screen_name=TwitterAPI&include_entities=true');
```

Within the `$request` variable, there will be a data property `$request->data`. This stores the JSON object.

The only thing left to do is decode the data property to get access to all the information.

```
$request = drupal_http_request('https://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json?screen_name=TwitterAPI&include_entities=true');
return drupal_json_decode($request->data);
```

**JSON Endpoints**

The last item I want to demonstrate is how to create a JSON endpoint for content on a Drupal site. For example, if you navigate to example.com/node/1/json the website will output a JSON version of the content. This will show you how to output a full JSON page using the [drupal_json_output()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_json_output/7) function.

1. First we must implement a menu item using the hook_menu. The menu item path needs to be "node/%node/json". For more details on how to use hook_menu check out the [API documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7).

   /**

   - Implements hook_menu().
     */
     function ww_json_example_menu() { 
     $items['node/%node/json'] = array(
     'page callback' => 'ww_json_example_endpoint',
     'page arguments' => array(1),
     'access arguments' => array('access content'),
     );
     return $items;
     }
2. Create a "page callback" function for the menu item. Also, make sure that you add a $node variable to the function signature. For this example, the page callback is "ww_json_example_endpoint". Finally, we pass the $node object through to the [drupal_json_output()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_json_output/7) function. If you go to node/1/json you should just see outputted JSON code.

function ww_json_example_endpoint($node) {
  drupal_json_output($node);
}